# Questions on beta sites are way older than they should be

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, beta-phase

The ["Personal Finance and Money"](https://money.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site just launched its private beta today.  Yet, the [oldest question on the site](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2/whats-better-an-unsecured-line-of-credit-or-a-secured-line-of-credit-like-a-he) was supposedly posted in October 2009! Where did this question and its timestamp come from?

[image: screenshot]

(Edit: after I posted this question I thought of one possible explanation -- this new site could be merging with an old SE 1.0 site, and inherited all its questions. Is this correct?)

Comment: probably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was merged with http://www.basicallymoney.com

Comment: Correct :-)  I launched BasicallyMoney.com as a **StackExchange 1.0** site in October, 2009.  When **StackExchange 2.0** was proposed and area51 launched, I submitted my proposal for the site as one to *migrate* the SE 1.0 site into the SE 2.0 network.  This is the first such site to undergo such a migration.